# AttributeError: 'GzipFile' object has no attribute '_buffer' when reading from gzip file

Tags: python, io, gzip

When I attempt to read from a `.gz` file line by line with the `gzip` module in Python, I get a crash:

```
  File "/home/user/path/to/example.py", line 40, in run
    for line in handle:
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/py38/lib/python3.10/gzip.py", line 399, in readline
    return self._buffer.readline(size)
AttributeError: 'GzipFile' object has no attribute '_buffer'
```

Here's my code:

```py
import gzip

handle = gzip.open("path/to/file.txt.gz", "w")
for line in handle:
    print(line)
```

I'm using Python 3.10 on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have opened the file in **write mode, not read mode**.

Correct code:

```py
import gzip

handle = gzip.open("path/to/file.txt.gz", "r")
for line in handle:
    print(line)
```

By changing the `"w"` to a `"r"` in the `gzip.open()` call, we choose to open the file in read mode rather than write mode.

*(Note for reference: this error has a non-obvious cause and I couldn't find this elsewhere on here, so documenting both the error and the solution to help others)*